# How to validate ul and li for select list using validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I need to use ul li for select option because need to do some style on that, but unfortunately, I cannot use validate for that because not the input element.

this form is the multi form, here some part of my code

```
  <form id="my-form" class="mwf-form" method="POST" action="">

    <fieldset id="email-id">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <ul class="psa_form_area">

            <li class="mwf-field">
              <p>Please enter your e-mail address</p>
            </li>

            <li data-mwf-container="email-add" class="mwf-field">
              <label class="mwf-label" for="email-add">
                E-mail</label>
              <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
              <div class="mwf-input">

                <input id="email-add" name="email-add" class="mwf-text line ptm " type="email">

              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>


          <ul>

            <li data-mwf-container="next" class="mwf-button mwf-next">

              <input type="button" value="Continue" id="next-button" data-mwf-id="next" class="next" name="next">

            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="personal_information">

      <ul>
        <li class="mwf-field">
          <h3>Personal data</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="psa_form_area">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <li data-mwf-container="email-add" class="mwf-field">
              <label class="mwf-label" for="email-add">
                E-mail</label>
              <div class="mwf-input">
                <input id="email-add2" readonly="readonly" style="border:0" type="text">
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">


            <li data-mwf-container="country" class="mwf-field">
              <label class="mwf-label" for="country">
                Country
                <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="dropdown mwf-input custom-select open" id="selectCountry">
                <button id="mybtn" class="button-dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                  <span class="button-text selected">Select Country...</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu" id="dropdown" name="country" required="" aria-required="true">
                  <li id="dropdw" class="dropdown-header">Select Country:</li>
                  <li id="1"><a href="#" btattached="true">Albania</a></li>
                  <li id="2"><a href="#" btattached="true">Austria</a></li>
                  <li id="3"><a href="#" btattached="true">Belgium</a></li>
                  <li id="4"><a href="#" btattached="true">Bosnia and Herzegovina</a></li>
                  <li id="5"><a href="#" btattached="true">Bulgaria</a></li>
                  <li id="6"><a href="#" btattached="true">Croatia</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <li data-mwf-container="lang" class="mwf-field">
              <label class="mwf-label" for="lang">
                Language
              </label>
              <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
              <div class="dropdown mwf-input custom-select" id="selectLang">
                <button id="mybtn" class="button-dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="button-text selected">Select Language...</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu" id="dropdown">
                  <li id="dropdw" class="dropdown-header">Select Languange:</li>
                  <li id="1"><a href="#">German</a></li>
                  <li id="2"><a href="#">English</a></li>
                  <li id="3"><a href="#">Dutch</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <li data-mwf-container="fname" class="mwf-field">
                                    <label class="mwf-label" for="fname">
                                    First name</label>

                                    <div class="mwf-input">
                                        <input id="fname" name="fname" class="mwf-text line ptm " type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <li data-mwf-container="lname" class="mwf-field ">
                                    <label class="mwf-label" for="lname">
                                    Last name</label>
                                    <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
                                    <div class="mwf-input">
                                        <input id="lname" name="lname" class="mwf-text line ptm " type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul class="psa_form_area">
                                        <li data-mwf-container="_cancel_EN5138" class="mwf-button mwf-reset">
                                            <input type="reset" value="Reset"
                                            data-mwf-submit="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;cancel&quot;}"
                                            data-mwf-id="_cancel_EN5138" >
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-mwf-container="submit" class="mwf-button mwf-submit">
                                            <input type="button" value="Submit" data-mwf-id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <fieldset id="confirm">
    <p>Thank you very much for your registration! An automatic e-mail response has been sent to {{email}}
    </p>
  </fieldset>
```

jQuery code

```
$(".mwf-next, .mwf-submit").click(function(){
    form.validate({
          errorElement: 'span',
          errorClass: 'help-block',
          highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.mwf-field').addClass("has-error");

          },
          unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest('.mwf-field').removeClass("has-error");
          },
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.mwf-option').length) {
              error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
              error.insertAfter(element);
            }
          },
          rules: {
            'email-add': {
              required: {
                depends: function() {
                  $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                  return true;
                }
              },
              email: true
            },
            country: {
              selectList: true,
              required: true

            },

            lname: {
              required: true
            },

            lang: {
              required: true
            }


          },

          messages: {
            'email-add': {
              required: "Please enter an email address",
              email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            country: {
              required: "Please select country"

            },


            lname: {
              required: "Last name required"
            },

            lang: {
              required: "Languange required"
            }


          }
        });
        $('ul#dropdown').each(function() {
          $(this).find('ul#dropdown').find('li').each(function() {
            if ($(this).selected === "0") {
              //alert("please select");
            } else {
              $(this).closest('.mwf-field').removeClass('has-error');
            }
          });
        });
        if ($("ul#dropdown li.selected").length > 0) {
          var le = $('ul#dropdown li.selected');
          //alert(le .length);
        }
        if (form.valid() === true) {
          if ($('#email-id').is(":visible")) {
            current_fs = $('#email-id');
            next_fs = $('#personal_information');
          } else if ($('#personal_information').is(":visible")) {
            current_fs = $('#personal_information');
            next_fs = $('#confirm');
          }
          next_fs.show();
          current_fs.hide();
          email1 = $('#email-add').val();
          email2 = $('#email-add2').val(email1);
          email2.css("font-weight", "Bold");
          var template = "<p>Thank you very much for your registration An automatic e-mail response has been sent to <strong>" + email1 + " </strong></p>";
          //var html = Mustache.to_html(template);
          $('#confirm').html(template);
        }


      }); //end function validate

    });
```

How to solve this issue? any alternative for that?

here is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/jCos/7y7rj9eq/7/

sorry i dont know how to include font style in jsfiddle, so select list not seem correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to find the `id` of that `li` ,like this..

`$('#dropdown li.selected').attr('id');`

this will give you the selected `li` value i.e. `id` in your case, give bydefault `id="0"` to `<li id="dropdw" class="dropdown-header">Select Country:</li>` this `li`, so that you can check or you can check `dropdw` id as well.

Comment: Thanks @Minksmnm for the answer, could you please help to correct my code in jsfiddle? not really clear how to do it, mean need to write separate validate from validate plugin?